# About Climbing n-th stair problem with 2, 3 or 4 steps

Tags: c++

My problem is

> You are climbing a stair case. Each time you can either make 2 step, 3 steps or 4 steps. The staircase has `n` steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb the staircase?

This is my code:

```
int count(int n) 
{ 
    int a[n + 1]; 
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 0; 
    a[2] = 1;
    a[3] = 1;
    a[4] = 2;
    for (int i = 5; i <= n; i++) 
        a[i] = a[i - 4] + a[i - 3] 
                + a[i - 2]; 
  
    return a[n]; 
}
```

Is my code correct for every test? and how to check when `N` is very high to count?

Comment: `int a[n + 1];` is not C++. It's a GNU extension. Use `std::vector<int>` instead :)

Comment: All variable names in this program are meaningless.  Are you asking us to derive your algorithm and prove whether it's correct?  That's _your_ job as a developer.  If you need, try generating a large test set and calculate its answer using simple brute force techniques and then compare that result to your algorithm.

Comment: Sorry for the bad asking, this is my first time asking a question here, thank you for your recommend.

Comment: Use induction to prove that it's correct (or not).

Comment: Find help with understanding this community by taking the [tour] and especially on [ask]. That info makes things easier here.

Comment: "all the test cases" is undefined. You need to specify a maximum number of steps. For ludicrously long stairs your code will fail. Though for stairs that long, breathing problems would probably prevent anybody from counting to 4 anyway....

Comment: Describing how you tested and explaining the logic of the algorithm you implemented might both help - and might overlap a lot. I suspect that using an array and a loop is cause for TLE, just in case an online judge is involved in this....